# Run USP & SQL Query In One Connection

Tags: sql-server, excel

In Excel, I know you can do both of these in separate connections, but is it possible to do this in 1 connection?  I have tried in one connection, but it throws this error message.  If I do each separately no error.  And just in case here are the steps I use:

> Data Tab --> From Other Sources --> From SQL Server 
>   Enter Credentials
>   Chose table or view
>   Select properties
>   Select definition tab
>   Change type to SQL
>   Change command text to query
>   Click Okay
>   Click Okay again
>   Excel complains about garbage...click okay

AND Blamo!  Here is the error
[image]

Comment: what does the stored procedure do?

Comment: Runs an update query.  Both of these will run successfully if I run on the server I am attempting to connect to via SSMS.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You seem to be trying to retrieve external data yet you state you want to run a stored procedure. You can use a procedure to return data but you can't use two statement like this. As posted your question just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @SeanLange Run 2 statements from within the Excel Window.  1 Update Statement, then 1 Select statement.  Instead of 2 connections, can it be done in 1?

Comment: Not the way you are trying it. You are using the external data tool, it is not some magical tool that allows you to run a stored procedure and then get data. Why not just create a new procedure that executes the existing procedure and then returns the data you want?